# Postgresql Docker container not initializing with all the columns in the dump file

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So, the initialization was working properly before I introduced new features in which I added a column to my user's table called image and it has text data as shown below,

[image: users table dump file]

I don't know why but what is happening is that this image column is not being initialized in the docker container once I run docker-compose up, and due to this I am getting an error from the backend saying that image column doesn't exist. I went into the postgres container and checked if image column existed and this is what came out.

[image]

I believed it was a problem with image being maybe a keyword but I ruled that out because another table before this feature was added is working fine as shown below

[image]

This is still working fine, but only the user's table is facing this weird problem, any suggestions would be immensely appreciated.

EDIT-1:- What's even weirder is that I tried adding the image column manually by going into the Postgres container and it works
[image: Adding image column manually]

Comment: Weird indeed. Are you perhaps mixing up schemas? The new `users` table might be somewhere else ,)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution but have absolutely no way how it works and stumbled on it by accident, so here goes,

In my dockerfile for the database called Dockerfile.db, the image I was using earlier was 11.2 version, so I changed to see if it would work.

When I did it gave me an error that basically translated to that I had initialized the volume containing the data in 11.2 and now since it is 13.2 it won't work, so I removed the older volumes and rerun it, VOILA!! IT WORKS

It could have been a volume error or an postgres version error, guess we will never find out.

Dockerfile.db

```
#FROM postgres:11.2-alpine 

FROM postgres:13.2-alpine
COPY ./humaine_backup_latest.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
# The SQL file is the dump file from my local environment which I use to initialize the database
```